# Access worksheet variables from workbook events

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event which needs to know details about a range from *before* the change event ran. To do this, one part of the event logs the current state, another part looks at the logs from the previous time the event ran, and works with them. I'm saving the logs as global variables. My code steps look like this:

```
'Declarations:
Private oldT() As Double
Private oldHigh As Range
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'''
'1) Read range stored in oldHigh
'''
Dim newHigh as Range
Dim newT() As Double
Set newHigh= Target 'range we are currently working on
ReDim newT(1 To newHigh.Cells.Count, 1 To 3) '
'''
'2) Loop through each Cell in newHigh and pass 3 details to newT()
'   This saves the current state
'''
'3) Make temporary change to newHigh
'''
'4) Loop through oldHigh, using the values saved in oldT() to reset it
'''
Set oldHigh = newHigh'log where you made the temporary changes
oldT = newT 'and what the cells were before the changes
End Sub
```

I do not initialise the variables with a `Workbook_Open`, instead I have an error check in my selection change code (before step 1) in case `oldHigh` is empty.

This is all fine, except that I now realise that if I save and exit, the last reset action does not take place. So I decided to carry out step `4)` in a `Workbook_BeforeSave` event, that way the workbook doesn't save the temporary change (making it permenant)
That code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim subCell As Range
    Dim oldHigh As Range: Set oldHigh = [a1]
    For i = 1 To lastCol 'reset
        Set subCell = oldHigh(1, i)
        With subCell.Interior
            .Color = oldT(i, 3)
            .TintAndShade = oldT(i, 2)
            .Pattern = oldT(i, 1)
        End With
    Next i
    Set oldHigh = Nothing 'Required if user saves but does not exit,
                          'This makes the workbook look as if it is freshly opened 
                          'Which is what my code is designed to handle
End Sub
```

(As you can see, the data saved is fill info, I temporarily change the fill to highlight the selection, then change it back to how it was afterwards)

### The problem

When I run that save event, the code can't access `oldT()` or `oldHigh`. I guessed this was because they are `Private` so I made them `Public`, but that gave the following error:
[image: Error message]

How can I access these worsheet variables from the workbook event?

#### Actual Code:

To avoid confusion. Note `newHigh` is called `highRng` here

```
Private oldT() As Double
Private oldHigh As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myTbl As ListObject
Dim oldHighTest As Boolean
Set myTbl = Me.ListObjects(1)
If oldHigh Is Nothing Then
    oldHighTest = True
Else
    oldHighTest = Intersect(oldHigh, Target) Is Nothing
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, myTbl.Range) Is Nothing And oldHighTest Then ' highlight cells in table only when new row of table is selected
    appMod False
    On Error GoTo e
    Dim tl As Range, highRng As Range, subCell As Range
    Dim newT() As Double, lastCol As Long, i As Long
    Set tl = myTbl.HeaderRowRange(1)
    Set highRng = Me.Range(Cells(Target.Row, tl.Column), Cells(Target.Row, tl.Column + myTbl.ListColumns.Count - 1))
    lastCol = highRng.Columns.Count
    ReDim newT(1 To lastCol, 1 To 3) '
    For i = 1 To lastCol 'save
        Set subCell = highRng(1, i)
        With subCell.Interior
            newT(i, 1) = .Pattern
            newT(i, 2) = .TintAndShade
            newT(i, 3) = .Color
        End With
    Next i
    With highRng.Interior 'highlight
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .TintAndShade = 1
        .Color = 4189681
    End With
    For i = 1 To lastCol 'reset last highlight using last save
        Set subCell = oldHigh(1, i)
        With subCell.Interior
            .Color = oldT(i, 3)
            .TintAndShade = oldT(i, 2)
            .Pattern = oldT(i, 1)
        End With
    Next i

e:  appMod True
    Set oldHigh = highRng
    oldT = newT
End If

End Sub
```

Placed in `Sheet1` code, and highlights a row of table1 (or the 1st `ListObject` in the page, in case I change the table name)
 Where `appMod` calls

```
Public Sub appMod(t As Boolean)
With Application
    .EnableEvents = t
    .ScreenUpdating = t
End With
End Sub
```

The problem arises when changing

```
Private oldT()
```

to

```
Public oldT()
```

But no issues making `oldHigh` `Public` , only that it is still not picked up in the `ThisWorkbook` code (it is seen as blank when it isn't)

Comment: Just had a poke around msdn, perhaps I could employ `Static` instead of global variables, altough I'm not sure if that would help my `Workbook_BeforeSave` access them.

Comment: in your procedure selectionchange you define Highrange, you use highrng and finally newhigh, to my understanding, you probably mean to use newhigh for all. highrange is not used, highrng is not initialised ....

Comment: @h2so4 Sorry, fixed now, that was a legacy of the actual code

Comment: is declarations: part of your code ? if yes remove it

Comment: @h2so4 Fixed (it wasn't actually in my real code). I've also added the actual code to avoid similar issues. It should highlight the correct row of the first table on whichever sheet the code is placed. I've also clarified how to raise the error message.

Comment: define public oldT() in a new module, instead of in the sheet1

Comment: @h2so4 I'll accept that as answer, maybe some additional explanation would be nice

Comment: as the error message says, public arrays are not allowed in object module (in this case you try to define a public array within sheet1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment, insert the instruction in a new module instead of sheet1

```
public oldT()
```

the error message mentions public arrays are not allowed in object module. I could not find more info on msdn.